# GoogleMap api key for debug node

Tags: android, google-maps

I have written an android application. I used GoogleMap. Codes are true. It is executing without any problem. But there is a problem with my layout xml. Codes are here.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="????"
```

Where can i obtain an api key for my debug node. I won't upload the application to the android market.

Comment: I guess, google will provide you with the api key..

Comment: But I will not upload to the market this application. Only I want to see the map.

Answer (score 0):

You do the same step as you'd do with a real key. But instead of using a release keystore for your app you use the default/debug keystore which is located in: `users\xx_your_name\.android\debug.keystore`

The walkthrough on everything for Google mapsv2 is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). Look under **Obtaining an API Key**.

Comment: Can you give me a link where i can get a real key.

Comment: Never mind that I see the old is deprecated so you have to use the new one :)

Comment: I guess ,new mapsv2. Because I have used MapView class.

Comment: are there any temporary keys?

Comment: @emrerme no temporary keys, you'll have to use your debug key and generate a sha1 fingerprint and then use this in google services to register for map content.

Comment: Ok I see. Can u give me a link?

Comment: @emrerme I did in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Signup here to get the GOOGLE API KEY for the Maps

**https://developers.google.com/maps/signup**

This page also help you to generate the API key for Google maps:-
 **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/**

Answer (score 0):

Use Google map v2. Older key been deprecated on March. Use SHA-1 to register in google console.

https://code.google.com/apis/console/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Excellent tutorial is here for google map v2

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html